# Как применить динамический SVG градиент?

Tags: jquery, svg

Делаю градиент с помощью jQuery, добавляю этот градиент в SVG указываю свойства fill, но ничего не происходит:

```
$(function(){
    jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

        jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                if (imgClass.search(/gradient/) !== -1) {
                    var gradient = '<linearGradient id="gradient">' +
                      '<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0086b3"/>' +
                    '<stop offset="51%" stop-color="#2aaad5"/>' +
                    '<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0086b3"/>' +
                    '</linearGradient>';
                  $svg.prepend($.parseXML(gradient).documentElement);
                  $svg.find('path').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeAttr('style');
                    $(this).attr('fill', 'url(#gradient)');
                  });
                }
            }

            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

            // Check if the viewport is set, else we gonna set it if we can.
            if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
                $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
            }

            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);

        }, 'xml');

    });
});
```

Полный пример здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/mxww27bv/1/

Я так понимаю что градиент не применяется из-за того, что DOM самого SVG не знает про этот градиент, но как заставить применить его?

Comment: Хороший вопрос.   А какой хотите получить конечный результат, как анимированная заставка Windows7 или что-то другое?  Подробней пожалуйста опишите что хотите получить на финише. Ещё лучше, **в дополнение** нарисуйте картинку

Comment: @Alexandr_T да нет, все просто, надо чтобы градиент применился таки к SVG, а в данном случае он не применяется, SVG становится просто без заливки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение кроется в элементарном понимании работы с SVG градиент корректно добавляется в SVG такой функцией:

```
var createGradient = function (svg, id, stops) {
    var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
    var grad = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'linearGradient');
    grad.setAttribute('id', id);
    for (var i = 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
        var attrs = stops[i];
        var stop = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'stop');
        for (var attr in attrs) {
            if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr))
                stop.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
        }
        grad.appendChild(stop);
    }
    var defs = svg.querySelector('defs') ||
        svg.insertBefore( document.createElementNS(svgNS,'defs'), svg.firstChild );
    return defs.appendChild(grad);
}
```

Вот реализованный пример: http://jsfiddle.net/mxww27bv/7/

Мой вопрос уже поднимался и решение тоже уже было: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10898304/1280133

Спасибо всем за помощь.

**UPD:** Выкладываю полный пример здесь:

```js
$(function(){
    jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
    
        jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
    
            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                if (imgClass.search(/gradient/) !== -1) {
                 createGradient($svg[0], 'gradient', [
                   { offset: '0%', 'stop-color': '#0086b3'},
                    { offset: '51%', 'stop-color': '#2aaad5'},
                    { offset: '100%', 'stop-color': '#0086b3'}
                  ]);
                  $svg.find('path').each(function () {
                   $(this).removeAttr('style');
                   $(this).attr('fill', 'url(#gradient)');
                  });
                }
            }
    
            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
            
            // Check if the viewport is set, else we gonna set it if we can.
            if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
                $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
            }
    
            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);
    
        }, 'xml');
    
    });
    
    function createGradient(svg, id, stops) {
     var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
      var grad = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'linearGradient');
      grad.setAttribute('id', id);
      for (var i = 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
       var attrs = stops[i];
        var stop = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'stop');
        for (var attr in attrs) {
         if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr))
           stop.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
        }
        grad.appendChild(stop);
      }
      var defs = svg.querySelector('defs') || svg.insertBefore( document.createElementNS(svgNS,'defs'), svg.firstChild );
      return defs.appendChild(grad);
    }
});
```

```css
svg {width: 300px; height: 300px;}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg" alt="Microsoft" width="350" />
<img class="svg gradient" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Windows_logo_-_2012_%28red%29.svg" alt="Microsoft" width="350" height="350">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```